# How to check if I have a specific value inside my localStorage?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, local-storage

I want to check if the name value I put in the input exists inside my local Storage by the key 'username'. [ just to be clear I make an array that every time I make a new register it adding the new username to the array and to the localStorage I insert the array ]

javascript:

```
 function login(user.value,pass.value){

    if(localStorage.getItem('username').indexOf(user) >= 0  )
        alert('hey')
    }
```

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Login Page </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/loginpage.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/loginpage.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div>
    <input id="user" type="text" placeholder="Enter the Name"/>
    <input id="pass" type="password" placeholder="Enter the Color"/>
    <button onclick="login(user,pass)">Login</button>
    <a href='file:///C:/Users/DELL/Desktop/HackerU/Web/site/site.html'> <button>New Register</button></a>   
    </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong `.` is not a valid parameter identifier

```
function login(user, pass) {
    if(localStorage.getItem('username').indexOf(user) >= 0  ) {
        alert('hey');
    }
}
```

Comment: but my username value is : omer1,omer2,omer3
and if i do username === user its wont work because i want to check only if i have omer1 inside username